# Submit Edit automatically returns to the Edit page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, repository-pattern

I'm coding my admin can `delete` and `edit` a user's account. I was able to get that account out based on `Id Account` but when I click submit `edit` my page automatically returns to `Edit` page. The code and image are as follows:

**View**

```
   @model Megatron.Models.ApplicationUser

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit Account";
}

<h1>Edit Account</h1>


<hr />
@Html.HiddenFor(u => u.Id)
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="EditAcount">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FullName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FullName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FullName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            @*<div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>*@
            @*<div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PhoneNumber" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="PhoneNumber" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PhoneNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>*@
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Edit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a typo in your form `asp-action` field.

It should be:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(u => u.Id)
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="EditAccount">
        ...
```

Now, when you will click on `Edit` button, it should properly go to the correct HttpPost `EditAccount` method.